# SwiftyJSON cant get value from json

Tags: json, swift

im using SwiftyJSON to get some Strings out of this **JSON**: http://api.randomuser.me but all i am getting is **nil**

```
let urlPath = "http://api.randomuser.me"

func getJSON(urlToRequest: String) -> NSData {
    return NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: urlToRequest)!)!
}

func getRandomUser() {

    let encodedData = NSString(data: getJSON(urlPath), encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    let json = JSON(rawValue: encodedData!)!

    println(json["results"][0]["user"].string)

}
```

... i also tried:

```
let urlPath = "http://api.randomuser.me"

    func getJSON(urlToRequest: String) -> NSData {
        return NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: urlToRequest)!)!
    }

    func getRandomUser() {

        let json = JSON(getJSON(urlPath))

        println(json["results"][0]["user"].string)

    }
```

i dont know why it doesn't print the correct result

Comment: json["results"][0]["user"] is a dict, so accessing string var on it will return nil...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try this:

```
var error: NSError?
let data = getJSON(urlPath)
let json = JSON(data: data, options: nil, error: &error)
//
println(json["results"][0]["user"]["name"]["first"].stringValue)
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me ... but i don't understand why!? And i'm pretty sure i have tried this already ^^

Comment: You should set NSUTF8StringEncoding only for String data, in this case you have Dictionary data.